# Uploading files and making a directory with PHP

Tags: php, file, upload

Not sure if anybody can/will answer this, I am just starting php programming and was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction. I want to have a page where you select and image to upload and you can specify a folder name, the script creates the folder and puts the image in that folder that was specified in the html form. i.e I upload john.jpg and I put in john as a folder name, so that when I go to get the image its in uploads/john/john.jpg . Any help would be usefull

Comment: We aren't going to do the work for you.  What have you tried so far?  Can you post some of your code?  One thing with letting people decide their own folder to upload the file to is security.  You don't want people to be able to go `../../../etc/` for folder and `passwd` for file name.

Comment: Being a noob is okay. Not searching StackOverflow before asking is not. Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=file+upload+php and point out why none of these helped solve your problem. Also see [Handling File Uploads in the PHP Manual](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)

Answer (score 2):

**To create a directory:**
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php

**A nice tutorial on PHP uploads**
http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Welcome on SO!

Answer (score 0):

Sean,
I wish someone had directed me to frameworks when I first started.  It would have saved me all the hassle.  Zend, CakePHP, Symphony are all good frameworks.  I personally use Yii.  It's a life saver.

[Yii site](http://www.yiiframework.com/)

Go there, get the framework and read the documentation.  It makes it all so much easier.

Comment: Terrible idea. Someone who just got started has enough to do with getting to grips with PHP. Pointing them to a framework will make them learn the framework and not PHP. And depending on the framework the learning curve could be overwhelming.

Comment: Frameworks aren't good for when you're first jumping into a programming language. It's a lot like trying to learn English by writing War and Peace. You have the double headache of learning the language's syntax as well as the framework's. Best to go for the language and get comfortable with it, THEN learn the framework.

Comment: I hear you guys.  I've seen both at my work.  People who grew up on the language first and people who jumped in it all feet first.  The learning curve is steep, but the guys who did it all up front started creating quality work sooner than the guys who didn't.